# How to fade video using a custom curve function in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to fade out a video using a different transition curve than what the [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter uses (which is probably linear).

For audio, I can easily choose from a wide variety of curves that the [afade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) filter provides, or I can supply a custom expression to the [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter, like (sin(PI/2 * min(1\, max(-1\, 1/2 * (t - 3)))) + 1)/2. For video, however, I could not find similar possibilities.

Based on its description, it seems to me that the [geq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq) filter could be misused to achieve this, but I couldn't get it to work. Additionally, it is very slow, probably because it works on individual pixels, even though the expression only depends on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to have custom curves, but for now, since a fade can be thought of as an animated blend between a black canvas and the video, we can use the blend filter to emulate a fade,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "format=gbrp,split[a][b];[a][b]blend=all_expr='A*(sin(PI/2*min(1\,max(-1\,1/2*(T-3))))+1)/2':enable='lte(t,5)',format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

First, a conversion to a RGB format is performed, since `0`-valued pixels (U/V) don't render black.

Then a split is performed since blend filter requires two inputs (we can use tblend but it doesn't support timeline editing - `enable`, so filtering will use unnecessary cycles and time).

In blend, an expression is supplied where `A` (the top layer) is given the fade expression and `B` is ignored, hence contributes nothing. `enable` is added to limit the time the filter is active.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!